# Passing a Camera Image as Bitmap Returns TransactionTooLarge Exception

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I am using camera kit library for my app. When I get the picture call back, I convert the byte array to bitmap and try to pass it to the next activity like this:

```
ab_capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            cameraView.captureImage(new CameraKitEventCallback<CameraKitImage>() {
                @Override
                public void callback(CameraKitImage cameraKitImage) {
                    byte[] jpeg = cameraKitImage.getJpeg();

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpeg, 0, jpeg.length);
                    Intent previewIntent = new Intent(ImageActivity.this, PreviewActivity.class);
                    previewIntent.putExtra("cam_image", bitmap);
                    startActivity(previewIntent); // implicit
                    finish();

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

but after clicking the button, app crashes and I get this error message:

```
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 3686928)
02-28 01:03:06.183 9579-9999/base.android.com.thumbsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraViewWorker
                                                                      Process: base.android.com.thumbsapp, PID: 9579
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1525)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4226)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4185)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:732)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4509)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4477)
                                                                          at base.android.com.thumbsapp.UI.Activities.ImageActivity$1$1.callback(ImageActivity.java:83)
                                                                          at base.android.com.thumbsapp.UI.Activities.ImageActivity$1$1.callback(ImageActivity.java:75)
                                                                          at com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraView$4.imageCaptured(CameraView.java:471)
                                                                          at com.wonderkiln.camerakit.Camera1$5.onPictureTaken(Camera1.java:427)
                                                                          at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1361)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                       Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 3686928 bytes
                                                                          at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:622)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3197)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1518)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4226) 
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54) 
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4185) 
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:732) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4509) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4477) 
                                                                          at base.android.com.thumbsapp.UI.Activities.ImageActivity$1$1.callback(ImageActivity.java:83) 
                                                                          at base.android.com.thumbsapp.UI.Activities.ImageActivity$1$1.callback(ImageActivity.java:75) 
                                                                          at com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraView$4.imageCaptured(CameraView.java:471) 
                                                                          at com.wonderkiln.camerakit.Camera1$5.onPictureTaken(Camera1.java:427) 
                                                                          at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1361) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
                                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

This error only occurs on a Nougat device. When I run on Lollipop, there is no error but it doesn't start the preview activity.

I need help understanding and resolving this error and also the problem with going to the next activity. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never pass this big data using intents. It will crash on most devices and is not well designed.

**First store file to disk then put its path to intent**

Comment: I want to save the file temporarily as user has option to make it permanent in next activity. How do I do that?

Comment: @JosephIbe Simply use fragments to present different information to the user. One for capturing and the second one for confirming or some edits all in one activity.

Answer (score 0):

> This error only occurs on a Nougat device

It will happen on the vast majority of Android devices.

> I need help understanding and resolving this error

Your `Intent` is too large, due to the large `Bitmap` extra.

The best solution is to not have two activities here. Have one activity with a changing UI, such as via the use of fragments.

Alternatively, *carefully* pass the `Bitmap` via a `static` field, making sure to set that field to `null` ASAP, so you do not have a long-term memory leak.

Comment: Can you give me an example of using a static field?